# Passing on ID on button click, for every user

Tags: php, mysql, button, input

I'd like to have an edit button for each database entry, and when the user clicks edit, it will only get the entry, that's alongside it. I've tried to use a hidden input like `<input type="hidden" name="userid" value=...>` but I don't really know where to put it, and how it could help.

So you can visualise it as well, I attached a photo of the table.

[image]

I hope you can help me, and if there's any other information that you need to know, just let me know please.

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="90%" style="margin: 0 auto">';
echo '<tr class="allUsers">';
echo '<th>Username</th>';
echo '<th>First name</th>';
echo '<th>Last name</th>';
echo '<th>Email</th>';
echo '<th>Year group</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 1</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 2</th>';
echo "<th>Subject 1's teacher</th>";
echo "<th>Subject 2's teacher</th>";
echo '<th>Privilege</th>';
echo '<th></th>';
echo '</tr>';
$getUsers = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");           
while($users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)){
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['first_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['last_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['year_group'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['subject'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['subject2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['teacher'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['teacher2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['is_admin'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><button name="editUser">Edit</button></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</form>';
}
if (isset($_POST['editUser'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['name'];
    // ....
}   
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: you want to edit it right in your table or bring the user to another page?

Comment: On the same page, presumably by hiding other entries, or just another page if that's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Method (hidden input)**

You can put the hidden input into every `<form></form>` that can be submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value=...>
```

**2. Method (`$_SESSION`)**

The second method is to save the `ID` in the session.
Advantages:

- It is not that easy to manipulate
- You do not need to paste it in every form that can be submitted.

In order to redirect the user to a next page, it would be helpful to send some kind of information about the row to edit. You can use the hidden input, if the information you will send is every time different. An ID that is for every row the same, can be saved in the session.

Comment: The problem I have at the moment is that the user id is always showing the last user's id. how could this be changed, so by clicking the button, it gets the right id ? Sorry I have no clue what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: @leveeee So the user id is every time different? Or did you mean the id of each row itself?

Comment: Yes, all of them have different IDs.

Comment: session would not be the best way for this. More esp if the logged in user is the admin

Comment: @leveeee ok, then I would recommend you method 1 as you mentioned in your question. But do not save the ID in plain text, use a secure hash-algorithm that creates dynamic hashes for the same value.

Comment: How do I link the input to the button or how will I be able to access the right ID, when the button is pressed?

Comment: @leveeee what I want to say is: Don't show the unique ID's from your db

Comment: @leveeee <input type="hidden" name="userid" value=...> just put this in your while loop

Comment: I don't want to show it, I just want to get the right row by pressing the button that's in the same row as the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137569/discussion-between-luca-jung-and-leveeee).

Answer (score 1):

**second method from Luca's answer.**

You can also edit the details on another page using the get method. `echo '<td><a herf="edit.php?id=' . urlencode(base64_encode($users['id'])) . '">Edit</a></td>';` we just gonna get the id in edit.php and continue.

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="90%" style="margin: 0 auto">';
echo '<tr class="allUsers">';
echo '<th>Username</th>';
echo '<th>First name</th>';
echo '<th>Last name</th>';
echo '<th>Email</th>';
echo '<th>Year group</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 1</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 2</th>';
echo "<th>Subject 1's teacher</th>";
echo "<th>Subject 2's teacher</th>";
echo '<th>Privilege</th>';
echo '<th></th>';
echo '</tr>';
$getUsers = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
while ($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['username'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['first_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['last_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['year_group'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['subject'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['subject2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['teacher'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['teacher2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $users['is_admin'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a herf="edit.php?id=' . urlencode(base64_encode($users['id'])) . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){

    $id = urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['id']));


    // do queries for  $id

  }else{

        // id does not exits do something

  }
```